# should I use a hash or array for broken links status?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I am getting an array of links back from a method call where `validate_pdf_links()` returns the array:

```
broken_pdf_links = broken_pdf_links + validate_pdf_links()
```

I am doing this on multiple pages with multiple links, so it works as follows:

1. Go to page.
2. Check all the links on that page using `validate_pdf_links()`.
3. Go to next page.
4. Repeat.

I want to know what page I was on when the link broke so I am using the following for page identification:

```
page_name = @browser.title
```

I want an output along the lines of:

```
broken_pdf_links.each do |pdf|
puts "The pdf link #{pdf} was broke on page #{page_name}
```

How should I assemble a hash or array to contain the elements and retrieve them in the manner I suggested?

EDIT:::::: currently trying:

```
broken_pdf_links.each {|pdf| broken_pdfs = broken_pdfs.push[pdf,page_name]}
```

to store, and then

```
broken_pdfs.each do |broke_pdf|
   puts "Link #{broke_pdf[0][0]} on Page #{broke_pdf[0][1]}\n"
   pdf_index += 1
end
```

to read

but i'm getting the error "TypeError: can't convert Array into Integer" on the store command.

Comment: Show us your code so we know what you tried.

Comment: @theTinMan I edited my question to show what I'm currently trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be more than one broken link on each page. A hash would be good here.

```
broken_pdf_links = {}

broken_pdf_links.merge!(:page_name => validate_pdf_links())

broken_pdf_links.each do |k,v|
  puts "The pdf link(s) #{v} was broken on page #{k}"
end
```

**Output:**

The pdf link(s) ["fail1", "fail2", "fail3"] was broken on page page_name

The pdf link(s) ["fail1"] was broken on page other_page

You could go further with the array and format it.

Comment: So if I get this right, you are using a hash with (symbol => array) where array is the result of validate_pdf_links() which I get, but then how do you store the string as a symbol?

Comment: the hash key doesn't have to be a symbol:

`hash = {}`
`hash.merge!({'key' => 'val'})`
`# => {"key"=>"val"}`

Comment: ok, you just confused me a little with the symbol in your example

Comment: Force of habit to use symbols :)

Comment: can you separate out the array in the hash?  Right now it's printing "On the Sales page, the a/a.pdfb/b.pdfc/c.pdf link(s) broke.  Anyway to do a/a.pdf, b/b.pdf, c/c.pdf link(s) broke. Or something similar to make it more readable

Comment: This is not a very elegant solution. I'm working on making it better:

https://gist.github.com/4502194

Comment: If your using Rails there is a `to_sentence` method for Array  http://api.rubyonrails.org/?q=to_sentence

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
broken_pdf_links.each {|pdf| broken_pdfs = broken_pdfs.push[pdf,page_name]}
```

Use:

```
broken_pdfs = broken_pdf_links.map { |pdf| [pdf,page_name] }
```

Mostly you were mixing up several ways of aggregating the sub-array.

You could use `map`, which is shorter and more direct, or:

```
broken_pdfs = []
broken_pdf.links.each do |pdf|
  broken_pdfs += [pdf, page_name]
end
```

An alternate to that is:

```
broken_pdfs = []
broken_pdf.links.each do |pdf|
  broken_pdfs.push([pdf, page_name])
end
```